# Android media.AudioTrack.finalize Throwing IllegalStateException: Binder has been finalized

Tags: java, android, daemon, mediarecorder

I am using a custom camera to record Videos on android.
The device experiencing the issue is a Nexus 5 with Android 6.0.1 on it.

When the camera finishes recording for only for **the 2nd time**, i get the following exception in the under-the-hood android media AudioTrack class.   This is something that is called implicitly by android, by the FinalizerDaemon, and not as a result of any code I execute directly.   So the FinalizerDaemon calls finalize on AudioTrack, and gets an IllegalStateException.

```
12-02 09:20:23.155 23705-23714/social.ivideo.greetings E/System: Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
12-02 09:20:23.160 23705-23714/social.ivideo.greetings E/System: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Binder has been finalized!
                                                                     at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                                     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:615)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.app.IAppOpsService$Stub$Proxy.stopWatchingMode(IAppOpsService.java:435)
                                                                     at android.media.PlayerBase.baseRelease(PlayerBase.java:136)
                                                                     at android.media.AudioTrack.finalize(AudioTrack.java:979)
                                                                     at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:222)
                                                                     at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:209)
                                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Perhaps I need to do some sort of clean up when the camera finishes recording?   Here's the current code I'm using when the recording stops:

```
 @Override
public void stopRecording(boolean wasCancelled, float duration) {
    if (mMediaRecorder != null) {
        mMediaRecorder.stop();
        mMediaRecorder.reset();

        if (flashState) {
            toggleFlash();
        }

        if (!wasCancelled) {
            callbacks.onFinishedRecording(null, mediaPath, duration, wasCancelled);
        }
    }
}
```

mMediaRecorder is an instance of MediaRecorder class.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

So I think this might be an Android bug. Looks suspiciously like this issue, which is marked as fixed in a "future version": https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37138597

Same Issue Reported in Android 7.1.2

fixed in Android 8.0 https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+log/aee6ee94675d56e71a42d52b16b8d8e5fa6ea3ff/media/java/android/media/PlayerBase.java